# Help with a exercise in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

Anyone could help me with this exercise, I don't know how to start.

Consider the one-dimensional dynamics of a particle with mass *m* under the influence of a harmonic potential. Its Hamiltonian is given by

$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}²}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m{\omega}²\hat{x}²=\hbar{\omega}(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}+\frac{1}{2})$

where $\omega$ is the oscillator's angular frequency and

$\hat{a}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\hat{x}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2m\omega\hbar}}\hat{p}$

The eigenstates $|n>$ $(n=0, 1,....)$ of the Hamiltonian are non-degenerate, are eigenstates of the number operator $\hat{N} =\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}$, and satisfy the relations

$\hat{a}|n>=\sqrt{n}|n-1>$
$\\$
$\hat{a}^\dagger|n>=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1>$

(a) Calculate the matrix elements of the operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ in the basis of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.

(b) Calculate the expectation value of the operator $\hat{x}²$ for any egenstate $|n>$.

(c) Calculate the ratio between the average total energy and the average potential energy of the system for any eigenstate $|n>.$

(d) Use the equation of motion of operators in the Heisenberg picture

$i\hbar\frac{d\hat{O}_{H}(t)}{dt}=[\hat{O}_{H}(t), \hat{H}]$

where $\hat{O}_{H}(t)=e^{i\hat{H}t/\hbar}\hat{O}e^{-i\hat{H}t/\hbar}$ , to obtain the time evolution of the operator $\hat{a}_{H}(t)$

Comment: I can understand not knowing where to start but it is important that you show your attempts at the problem. When I don't know what to do I try to make sure I can define all of the things I am talking about. For example, what is a matrix element of an operator? I am sure your book addresses this somewhere. Try saying what you think it is and then how does that definition relate to the problem at hand.

Comment: And just to supplement @LasersMatter answer, do you know how to find the expectation value (hint: does the word sandwhich ring a bell), if you understand this: then  a, b and c are all easy to do. James Binney of Oxford has a very good  q.m series on youtube. And a free pdf of his lectures is available

Comment: Hint: rearrange the formulae for $\hat{a},\,\hat{a}^\dagger$ in terms of $\hat{x},\,\hat{p}$ to give $\hat{x},\,\hat{p}$ in terms of $\hat{a},\,\hat{a}^\dagger$.